# Unable to read the parameters declared in testng.xml file

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

code:

```
package TestNG;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DataProvider {
    @Parameters("param1")
    @Test
    public void getParam(String MyName) {
        System.out.println("Parameter param1 value is :" + MyName);
    }
}
```

Testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="TestNG">
      <test name="DataProvider">
        <classes>
          <class name="TestNG.DataProvider"/>
          <parameter name="param1" value="10"/>
        </classes>
      </test> 
    </suite>
```

Error message :

```
SKIPPED: getParam
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'param1' is required by @Test on method getParam but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--422714061\testng-customsuite.xml
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:154)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:361)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:451)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1276)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:991)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1081)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
```

Note : Code in testng.xml is not color coded. Could this be some configuration issue and not able to read the parameter from testng.xml

Comment: testng.xml code in this post  is color coded but its not color coded in my eclipse

Comment: put the parameter line in <test> tag .. one level up

Answer (score 0):

I tried with same code provided, executed fine for me with out any exceptions. How did you created testng.xml file? if you written manually, instead of it, try below way

Right Click on src (or required package) in Eclipse >> Move to TestNG >> Select Convert to TestNG >> Click on Finish (you can provide names for suite and test here)

Open the created testng.xml file, place false for parallel """   parallel="false" """

Now run the testng.xml file. i request to good avoid naming convetion with reserved words like DataProvider, TestNG etc..

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the parameters tag outside the classes tag, either in the test tag or in the suite tag.

Make sure you are running either through the testng.xml with Run As -> Suite option or make the testng xml as your template xml in project properties.